# How to create an extended stored procedure in SQL Server 2000

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, extended-procedures

I need to create an extended stored procedure in SQL Server 2000 using Visual Studio. It worked fine in SQL Server 2008 and 2012. I followed the instructions described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164653.aspx) 
after adding the dll the stored procedure does not run!

The procedure to create extended procedure described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164653.aspx) for SQL Server 2012. But I need to create the same thing in the same way in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @marc_s how can i do this without CLR ?If i do this in c++ then would i need to use CLR ? Except using CL if there is any procedure plz let me know !

Comment: Maybe [this link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215790(v=sql.80).aspx) could be a starting point - it looks like pretty ugly C++ stuff ...

Comment: thanks again ! i've figured it out! Native C++ solved it ! If you want i can mark it as answer!if so then post an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just cannot do this.

SQL Server **2005** and newer introduced this **CLR support** - the abilty to include .NET code inside SQL Server.

SQL Server **2000** has no similar features. You'll need to resort to native C++ APIs - [check out this link here for starters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215790%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Simply not possible, I'm afraid.

If you look at the page you linked to (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164653.aspx) you'll see that SQL Server 2000 is not listed in the 'Other Versions' drop down.